# How do I use keys/values from stdout as input data for mySQL database updates?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dovecot

I'm trying to write a PHP script that automatically updates a MySQL database with output from a command in Linux. The command is "dovecot quota get -A" and it returns information about the quota usage of each user in the system. The output is formatted like this:

```
user1@domain.com Quota name=User quota Type=MESSAGE Value=2 Limit=- %=0
user1@domain.com Quota name=User quota Type=STORAGE Value=23560 Limit=- %=0
user2@domain.com Quota name=User quota Type=MESSAGE Value=115 Limit=- %=0
user2@domain.com Quota name=User quota Type=STORAGE Value=11541 Limit=- %=0
```

How would I go about pulling values from only a couple of the keys listed and then updating each row in the database with that info?

EDIT:

The actual output is now listed above. I haven't written much of the script yet. I'm really really new to scripting, so I don't really even know where to begin with something like this. Basically, though, the "Value" column (in the second and fourth rows) is the actual storage usage in kilobytes and I want to update our database with that info.

Comment: Ok, what have you written so far? Where did you get stuck? What does your data _actually_ look like? As it stands your question is a vague description of general requirements and not anything that we can reasonably answer.

Comment: Just updated the question with as much info as I can. I hope it's helpful! Let me know if there's any other info I need to provide.

Comment: You can start first by parsing the output into arrays. Parsing will be based on the output, and can be complicated based on factors. Then you can loop on that array to look for specifics that you then branch off to do some db actions. All of this is a lot of code to write, and not what SO is used for.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Where should I post this, then?